# How to do Javascript arithmetic within a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome

I have been looking at making a Chrome Extension, and have tried to test the capabilities of this by attempting some basic Javascript arithmetic. The example snippet attached should pull the calories from any BBC Good Food recipe page (i.e. https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/baked-chilli-jacket-potatoes) and calculate a 'Syn Value':

```js
function getCalories(){
var calories = document.querySelector('[itemprop=calories]').textContent;
}

function SynCalc(){
var syns = calories / 20;
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("scriptOut").innerHTML = syns;
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 10px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
      }

      button {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="click-this">Click Me</button>
 
 <p id="scriptOut"></p>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

If I replace `document.getElementById("scriptOut").innerHTML = syns;` with a string i.e. `document.getElementById("scriptOut").innerHTML = "Hello World";` then this works fine within the extension.

I have manifest.json, popup.html and popup.js within the same folder, so this isn't an issue.

Clearly my Javascript doesn't work correctly, despite me being able to run the 'getCalories' and 'SynCalc' functions within the console without issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not calling either of those functions in the code. What is the element `[itemprop=calories]`? That's not in your markup, and you might want to change it to `[data-itemprop="calories"]` to make it an explicit data attribute.

Comment: That is an on page element. How do I pull the attribute out of the page then? As I said, it works within the Console.

Comment: Then you should write some code to see what values are available and just dump them. It's a mistake to design and code an entire concept before you test it, as your reliance on misconceptions increases exponentially.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to point out:

1) At the moment the button is superfluous since you're attaching the click event listener to the document.

2) You're not calling either function.

3) You're better off returning values from the function instead of setting global variables.

4) You need to coerce the calorie text value to a number and return or else you'll get `NaN`.

Something like the following:

```js
function getCalories() {
  const calories = document.querySelector('[data-itemprop=calories]');
  return Number(calories.textContent);
}

function SynCalc() {
  return getCalories() / 20;
}

const button = document.getElementById('click-this');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('scriptOut').textContent = SynCalc();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
}

button {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div data-itemprop="calories">100</div>
<button id="click-this">Click Me</button>
<p id="scriptOut"></p>
```

Comment: Works in the snippet, but not in an Extension? When you click the button it doesn't write the result of the calc like it does within the above snippet?

Comment: Try moving `<script src="popup.js"></script>` to just before `</body>`. The DOM has to be ready before the script can pick up the elements.

Comment: Is there anything in the console after you click the button?

Comment: No nothing in the console

Comment: @J.Ayo: This really isn't a good way to learn to code. Whatever you've been told, or what you imagine, its *very much not* an easy way to get rich. In particular, writing a Chrome extension requires a knowledge of everything that you need for a web app plus some stuff that works only within Chrome. You need to learn HTML, JavaScript, the DOM, CSS, AJAX, and all the tools you choose before you can even start. Too many glib questions are taking up too much time on *Stack Overflow*.

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest.json be sure to set `permissions`:

```
{
    "name": "Your Extension Name",
    "description": "Base Level Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "your_extensions.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "commands": {
        "_execute_browser_action": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+Shift+F",
            "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+F"
        },
        "description": "calories"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ]
}
```

In the body of `popup.html` insert an hidden div where to inject the source page:

```
    ....
    <button id="click-this">Click Me</button>

    <div id="message" style="display: none;">Injecting here ...</div>

    <p id="scriptOut"></p>
    ....
```

popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
    if (request.action == "getSource") {
        //message.innerText = request.source;
        message.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', request.source );
    }
});

function onWindowLoad() {

    var message = document.querySelector('#message');

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "getPagesSource.js"
    }, function () {
        // If you try and inject into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
        }
    });

}

window.onload = onWindowLoad;


function getCalories() {
    return document.querySelector('[itemprop=calories]').textContent;
}

function SynCalc() {
    return getCalories() / 20;
}

document.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("scriptOut").innerHTML = SynCalc();
});
```

getPagesSource.js:

```
// @author Rob W <http://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w>
// Demo: var serialized_html = DOMtoString(document);

function DOMtoString(document_root) {
    var html = '',
        node = document_root.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            html += node.outerHTML;
            break;
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            html += node.nodeValue;
            break;
        case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            html += '<![CDATA[' + node.nodeValue + ']]>';
            break;
        case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
            html += '<!--' + node.nodeValue + '-->';
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
            // (X)HTML documents are identified by public identifiers
            html += "<!DOCTYPE " + node.name + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '') + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '') + '>\n';
            break;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return html;
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: DOMtoString(document)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to note first:

You need to make sure the browser finished rendering the page before you run DOM related scripts. See that `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ... )`? If not you may get something like: `document.getElementById("...") is null`.

You cannot just access `calories` and `syns` variables outside their functions. These are local variable. If you want the variables still available outside their functions, first define these variables outside their functions. Like this:

```
var calories = 0;
function a() {
   calories = 300;
}
a();
console.log(calories); // 300
```

And, your fully working extension here, so enjoy! I made and tested it using firefox but it should also work on chrome.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E87dCvQQHY6wzmuz1O-gGUWhAd9srIae/view?usp=sharing

Or code below:

popup.js

```
function getCalories() {
    return document.getElementById("examplecalories").textContent;
}

function SynCalc(calo) {
    return calo / 20;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("clickthis").addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("scriptOut").textContent = SynCalc(getCalories());
    });
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 10px;
            height: 250px;
            width: 150px;
        }

        button {
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <p>Example calories: <span id="examplecalories">300</span></p>
    <button id="clickthis">Click Me</button>
    <p id="scriptOut"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:**
You are creating a browser extension but there appears to be an issue with it working and asking people, why that is.

**Answer:**
You are trying to call a variable that is local to a function in a global environment, simply declare the variables outside of their functions such as

```
var syns, calories;
```

Whilst another user has already pointed out to you the DOMContentLoaded, I'm not 100% convinced that is necessary given the script would be carried out with a click event, surely the user would click the browser once the page has loaded and there is something to click on.

However that being said I don't see it doing any harm by being there

**Script:**
Example script for you

```js
var intSyns, intCalories ;
function funCheckPage(){
  intCalories = parseInt(document.querySelector('[itemprop=calories]').textContent);
  if (intCalories > 0){
    intSyns= calories / 20;
    document.getElementById("scriptOut").innerHTML = intSyns;
  }
}

function funActivateButton(){
  var el = document.getElementById("click-this");
  el.disabled = false;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funActivateButton(), false);
```

```css
body {margin: 10px; height: 250px; width: 150px}
button {font-size: 15px;}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="click-this" onclick="funCheckPage()" disabled>Click Me</button>
 <p id="scriptOut"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```